# Field not available in list from SOQL

Tags: apex, custom-field, null

I have a custom field that is populated by integration, and in certain cases a currency field will end up as blank.  It will not evaluate to null or 0.

SQL Execute from dev console log:

```
13:26:53:006 SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN [2]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Name, Last_Year_Sales__c FROM Account WHERE ((Last_Year_Sales__c = 0 OR Last_Year_Sales__c = NULL) AND Id = '0010y00001Y0cOWAAZ')
```

Results from Dev console log:

```
13:26:53:010 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [2]|accts|[{"Id":"0010y00001Y0cOWAAZ","Name":"TEST ACCOUNT"}]|0xe6fce69
```

The field Last_Year_Sales__c is included in the SELECT and the WHERE Clauses, and I'm getting the correct # of records (1), but the field Last_Year_Sales__c is not available in the returned list, so I cannot check if it is null or 0.

How do I get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the Field Level Security for `Last_Year_Sales__c ` ? do you have atleast read access?

Comment: Can you add more code?

Answer (score 1):

You might not have access to the field. You can go to your assigned profile and give FLS there.

Comment: Yes - the field is editable, and if I issue the query for an Account record that already has the field populated with a 0 or a calculated amount, there's no issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the `system.debug` which is not showing you the value `null`, but the field is infact returned with the query. Most likely the way the JSON is being deserialized in the debug log, it is skipping any `null` field values.

So you can always compare the value being returned by the field with `null` value, e.g., `myObj.Last_Year_Sales__c == null`, this will work fine.

---

As an example, I tried the below query in my DE Org where `AnnualRevenue` was set to `null`.

Query:

```
List<Account> aList = [SELECT Id, Name, AnnualRevenue FROM Account where Id = 'xxxx'];
Account a = aList.get(0);
system.debug('My Account: ' + a);
```

This is what I got in the debug log, the field was never printed.

```
USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|My Account: Account:{Id=xxxx, Name=United Oil & Gas Corp.}
```

And, the below condition to verify `null` worked just fine:

```
if(a.annualrevenue == null) {
    system.debug('It is null!');
} else {
    system.debug('It is NOT null!');
}
```

And the result was:

```
USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|It is null!
```